# CakePHP Form helper date field, but only use a select on the month. Allow day and year to be text field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**I'm trying to get a cakephp date field to output the month as a select, and the year as a text field rather than both as select fields.**

Here is what I believe would be the traditional Cake way of outputting a date type field both being selects (I added the dateFormat property to only currently show 2 select boxes (skipping the day)):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Payment.credit_card_expiration', array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'Expiration date', 'dateFormat' => 'MY')) ?>
```

What I temporarily did was I think kind of a hack, which is to split it into 2 fields.  I don't like it because it doesn't show the validationErrors for that field (the main issue) and it looks like ugly code (why write ugly code, especially if cake has a way to do this).

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('Payment.credit_card_expiration.month', array('type' => 'select', 'label' => 'Expiration date', 'options' => array('Month','Jan','Feb','...')));
echo $this->Form->input('Payment.credit_card_expiration.year', array('type' => 'text', 'label' => '&nbsp;', 'placeholder' => 'Year'));

if(isset($this->validationErrors['Payment']['credit_card_expiration'])) {
    echo '<div class="error-message">' . $this->validationErrors['Payment']['credit_card_expiration'][0] . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="span5">&nbsp;</div></div>';
}
?>
```

As a note, I've thought of possibly having to extend the FormHelper.  I haven't done that before, but I'm sure I could do it.  I'm just wondering if there is a built in way, or an elegant hack.

This is my first post on StackOverflow, so here we go, I'll see what happens.  Thank you for any thoughts or insight that you have, it's very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The CakePHP FormHelper say that you can use [`$this->Form->month()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3amonth) for that

Comment: Quick reply.  Thank you.  I'll see if I can get that to work. I appreciate it :)